# Data structure for storing data and calculating average

Tags: data-structures, average

In this problem, we are interested in a data structure that supports keeping infinite numbers of Y axis parallel vectors.

Each node contains location (X axis value) and height (Y axis value). We can assume there are no two vectors in the same location.

Please advise for an efficient data structure that supports:

1. `init((x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3)...(xn,yn))` - the DS will contain all n vectors, while VECTOR#i's location is xi VECTOR#i's hieght is yi. 
   We also know that `x1 < x2 < x3 < ... < xn` (nothing is known about the y) - complexity = O(n) on average
2. `insert(x,y)` - add vector with location x and height y. - complexity = O(logn) amortized on average.
3. `update(x,y)` - update vector#x's height to y. - complexity = O(logn) worst case
4. `average_around(x)` - return the heights average of logn neighbors of x - complexity = O(1) on average

Space Complexity: O(n)

Comment: the insert and update complexity makes me think about going for either a tree or a list with binary search.

Comment: when i look at the complexity requirements, i think the answer is with hash table + skip list

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no data-structure on the planet that can store 'infinite numbers' of anything :p. 
Seriously though, I'd go for Skiplist

Comment: @user1168623 Out of curiosity, how would you calculate the average of the log(n) neighbours in O(1)?

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide a full answer, but it might be a hint into the right direction.

**Basic ideas**:

- Let's assume you've calculated the average of `n` numbers `a_1,...,a_n`, then this average is `avg=(a_1+...+a_n)/n`. If we now replace `a_n` by `b`, we can recalculate the new average as follows: `avg'=(a_1+...+a_(n-1)+b)/n`, or - simpler - `avg'=((avg*n)-a_n+b)/n`. That means, if we exchange one element, we can recompute the average using the original average value by simple, fast operations, and don't need to re-iterate over all elements participating in the average.

Note: I assume that you want to have `log n` neighbours on each side, i.e. in total we have `2 log(n)` neighbours. You can simply adapt it if you want to have `log(n)` neighbours in total. Moreover, since `log n` in most cases won't be a natural number, I assume that you are talking about `floor(log n)`, but I'll just write `log n` for simplicity.

The main thing I'm considering is the fact that you have to tell the average around element `x` in O(1). Thus, I suppose you have to somehow precompute this average and store it. So, i would store in a node the following:

- x value
- y value
- average around

Note that `update(x,y)` runs strictly in O(log n) if you have this structure: If you update element `x` to height `y`, you have to consider the `2log(n)` neighbours whose average is affected by this change. You can recalculate each of these averages in O(1):

Let's assume, `update(x,y)` affects an element `b`, whose average is to be updated as well. Then, you simply multiply `average(b)` by the number of neighbours (`2log(n)` as stated above). Then, we subtract the old `y-value` of element `x`, and add the new (updated) `y`-value of `x`. After that, we divide by `2 log(n)`. This ensures that we now have the updated average for element `b`. This involved only some calculations and can thus be done in O(1). Since we have `2log n` neighbours, `update` runs in `O(2log n)=O(log n)`.

When you insert a new element `e`, you have to update the average of all elements affected by this new element `e`. This is *essentially* done like in the `update` routine. However, you have to be careful when `log n` (or precisely `floor(log n)`) changes its value. If `floor(log n)` stays the same (which it will, in most cases), then you can just do the analogue things described in `update`, however you will have to "remove" the height of one element, and "add" the height of the newly added element. In these "good" cases, run time is again strictly `O(log n)`.

Now, when `floor(log n)` is changing (incrementing by 1), you have to perform an update for *all* elements. That is, you have to do an O(1) operation for `n` elements, resulting in a running time of `O(n)`. However, it is very seldom the case that `floor(log n)` increments by 1 (you need to double the value of `n` to increment `floor(log n)` by 1 - assuming we are  talking about `log` to base 2, which is not uncommon in computer science). We denote this time by `c*n` or simply `cn`.

Thus, let's consider a sequence of inserts: The first insert needs an update: `c*1`, the second insert needs an update: `2*c`. The next time an expensive insert occurs, is the fourth insert: `4*c`, then the eight insert: `8c`, the sixtenth insert: `16*c`. The distance between two expensive inserts is doubled each time:

```
insert # 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18 ..
cost     1c 2c 1  4c 1  1  1  8c 1  1   1   1   1   1   1   16c 1   1  ..
```

Since no `remove` is required, we can continue with our analysis without any "special cases" and consider only a sequence of inserts. You see that most inserts cost 1, while few are expensive (1,2,4,8,16,32,...). So, if we have `m` inserts in total, we have roughly `log m` expensive inserts, and roughly `m-log m` cheap inserts. For simplicity, we assume simply `m` cheap inserts.

Then, we can compute the cost for `m` inserts:

```
         log m
         ----
         \      i
m*1 +    /     2   
         ----
          i=0
```

`m*1` counts the cheap operations, the sum the expensive ones. It can be shown that the whole thing is at most `4m` (in fact you can even show better estimates quite easily, but for us this suffices).

Thus, we see that `m` insert operations cost at most `4m` in total. Thus, a single insert operation costs at most `4m/m=4`, thus is `O(1)` amortized.

So, there are 2 things left:

- How to store all the entries?
- How to initialize the data structure in O(n)?

I suggest storing all entries in a skip-list, or some tree that guarantees logarithmic search-operations (otherwise, insert and update require more than O(log n) for finding the correct position). Note that the data structure must be buildable in O(n) - which should be no big problem assuming the elements are sorted according to their x-coordinate.

To initialize the data structure in O(n), I suggest beginning at element at index `log n` and computing its average the simple way (sum up, the `2log n` neighbours, divide by `2 log n`).

Then you move the index one further and compute `average(index)` using `average(index-1)`: `average(index)=average(index-1)*log(n)-y(index-1-log(n))+y(index+log(n))`.

That is, we follow a similar approach as in update. This means that computing the averages costs `O(log n + n*1)=O(n)`. Thus, we can compute the averages in O(n).

Note that you have to take some details into account which I haven't described here (e.g. border cases: element at index 1 does not have `log(n)` neighbours on both sides - how do you proceed with this?).